# Can not log into DD-WRT web GUI (but ssh!) after openVPN changes

Tags: networking, ssh, router, dd-wrt

I am running the *vpn* version of DD-WRT on my *Linksys WRT54G*. All worked great until I went into the web GUI and changed an IP address within the VPN settings. After I clicked **Apply Settings** I wasn't able to connect to the router anymore.
Even when I am on location I can not access the router using `192.168.1.1` anymore.
Luckily I set up remote SSH and am able to get into the router using ssh.
Trying to use remote web GUI which I also set up fails.
Before I was able to connect to the web GUI from a remote location using https and my assigned port, like so: `https://routerWANIP:20000`

`ping 192.168.1.1` sees delivered packages. So I can see my router in my network and the router functionality is intact as well.

Do you have any ideas what I could try to get web GUI access back up and running?
Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: I would simply reset the device.  You can then reconfigure the device from your backup settings.  You did save your settings before you change them right?

Comment: Uhm, of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you've blocked remove WebGUI, then these commands in ssh will help:

```
killall httpd 
/usr/sbin/httpd -h /www
```

If this doesn't help (e.i. you've changed default port and forgot the value) - thry this.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s <your.ip.addr> --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```